# Blender Principled BSDF shader missing, please help

Tags: materials

The Blender Principled BSDF shader is missing in my node editor. I'm using the latest Blender version 2.79. Please help :)[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch to Cycles rendering engine to be able to see/add Principled BSDF shader:

[image]